# Shopware 6 Image gallery and thumbnails

Tags: shopware6

how to change the image gallery thumbnails from vertical left alignment to horizontal bottom ??

changing configuration in twig files. at least should the image gallery thumbnails changed to horizontal bottom, and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score -1, accepted):

thank you for the help, i find another way to solve this, is when modify the `cms-element-image-gallery.html.twig` , and there change some configuration or reverse some css classes and it will work that thumbnails will be positioned in horizontal underneath the image slider and not

```
vertical left:      {% if galleryPosition == "left" %}
                    {% set gallerySliderOptions = gallerySliderOptions|replace_recursive({
                        thumbnailSlider: {
                            responsive: {
                                md: {
                                    axis: 'vertical'
                                },
                                lg: {
                                    axis: 'vertical'
                                },
                                xl: {
                                    axis: 'vertical'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }) %} this to vertical, and and here {% block element_image_gallery_inner_thumbnails_col %}
```

change the css  classes .

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom product page layout in the shopping experiences. You can't edit the default product page layout, but you can duplicate it in the context menu. When you edit the custom layout you can click the gallery element and open its settings. There you can set the preview image navigation to be placed underneath. Finally you have to navigate to the product and change the layout to your new custom one.

[image: Open settings for the element]
[image: Change placement to be undeath]

Comment: danke schön jedenfalls